# How to update multiple columns of a Pandas dataframe at once

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe with columns A, B and C, I want to update A and B as the result of applying a function over C. This function has one parameter and two return values.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [10, 20, 30],
    'C': [100, 200, 300]
})

# Define a function to apply
def my_function(x):
    return x*2, x*3  # This function returns a tuple

# Update
df[['A', 'B']] = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The function will return two series in a tuple. If you assign it to a tuple of df['A'] and df['B'] this will work:

```
(df['A'], df['B']) = my_function(df['C'])
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 | 300 | 100 |
| 1 | 400 | 600 | 200 |
| 2 | 600 | 900 | 300 |

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's easy, you just have to pack the results into a Series

```
# Use apply to update columns 'A' and 'B' based on column 'C'
df[['A', 'B']] = df['C'].apply(my_function).apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: The code will produce a warning about future deprecation.